# Firebase Hosting REST API - The caller does not have permission

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I called Hosting API referencing [Deploy to your site using the Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy) but I got the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

var key = require('./service-account.json');

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.hosting",
  null
);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(tokens.access_token);
});
```

Shell:

```
$ node main.js
ya29.c.Elp0...

$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
       -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.Elp0..." \
       -d '{
             "config": {
               "headers": [{
                 "glob": "**",
                 "headers": {
                   "Cache-Control": "max-age=1800"
                 }
               }]
             }
           }' \
  https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/sites/[project-id]/versions
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The project id of service-account.json and the project id in api endpoint are the same.

On the other hand, I only got successful response when [releases.list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/v1beta1/sites.releases/list) method:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.Elp0..." \
  https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/sites/[project-id]/releases
{
  "releases": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

#### Update:

The scope was wrong.

In the [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/v1beta1/sites.versions/create), authorization scope is one of firebase.hosting, firebase and cloud-platform but I only got successful response when using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`.

Comment: Hey boiyaa. Great to see that you found the problem. Would you mind posting it as an answer below? That way others who get the same problem are more likely to find the solution that worked for you.